# Find the expectation and variance of the fuction

Tags: expectation, variance, density-function

[image: Solve]

Cn someone give me the final answers for these? I found the pdf easily, the expectation and variance however have taken my time and i'm lost.

Answer (score 1):

Well, X is normal and Y therefore log-normal, then you can find everything you want from wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution.